# Spring Security HTTPBasic Failure Handler

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using the HTTPBasic authentication scheme in my spring security, and I would like to log all failed and successful login attempts. It seems like the general way to do so is to call a method upon login failure, kind of like this...

```
.and().formLogin().failureHandler(//method to call upon failure);
```

However, this requires the form login, and I am using HTTPBasic. How would we set this up so that it would have a failurehandler on an HTTPBasic authentication scheme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SecurityConfiguration.java**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

import com.service.UserService;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider auth = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        auth.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        auth.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return auth;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/welcome").permitAll().antMatchers("/secured")
            .authenticated().and().formLogin()
            .failureHandler(new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler()).permitAll().and().httpBasic();

    }

}
```

**LoginFailureHandler.java**

```
package com.config;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class LoginFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {



    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String email = request.getParameter("email");

        String redirectURL = "/login?error&email=" + email;

//       if (exception.getMessage().contains("OTP")) {
//              redirectURL = "/login?otp=true&email=" + email;
//          } else {
//              Customer customer = customerService.getCustomerByEmail(email);
//              if (customer.isOTPRequired()) {
//                  redirectURL = "/login?otp=true&email=" + email;
//              }
//          }
         
         
        super.setDefaultFailureUrl(redirectURL);

        super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation in your answer and not just post code

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.